# how to make train.txt file in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, training-data

I am using caffe net with python. I have train.txt file like this:

```
   train/1175-c/b0a1.bmp b0a1
   train/1175-c/b0a2.bmp b0a2
   train/1175-c/b0a3.bmp b0a3
   train/1175-c/b0a4.bmp b0a4
   train/1175-c/b0a5.bmp b0a5
   train/1175-c/b0a6.bmp b0a6
   train/1175-c/b0a7.bmp b0a7
   train/1175-c/b0a8.bmp b0a8
   train/1175-c/b0a9.bmp b0a9
   train/1175-c/b0aa.bmp b0aa
```

my questions:

1. Can I use hex instead of int at the end of each line?
2. About the label, does it need to start from 0

Or Should I change the above to:

```
train/1175-c/b0a1.bmp 45217
train/1175-c/b0a2.bmp 45218
train/1175-c/b0a3.bmp 45219
train/1175-c/b0a4.bmp 45220
train/1175-c/b0a5.bmp 45221
train/1175-c/b0a6.bmp 45222
train/1175-c/b0a7.bmp 45223
train/1175-c/b0a8.bmp 45224
train/1175-c/b0a9.bmp 45225
train/1175-c/b0aa.bmp 45226
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this `train.txt` list as input for [`convert_imageset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410) or as `source` for [`"ImageData"` layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L772-L801) then the second part of each line **must** be a numeric label.
The labels **must** start with 0 since they are used as indices into the predicted probability vectors when computing loss and accuracy. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36174031/1714410) for more information.

Comment: so the labels must start from 0? Should the labels be sequenced?

Comment: @xhsoldier yes.